# Ubuntu 14.04 wont boot.

Tags: boot, 14.04

i installed Ubuntu 14.04 from USB-Drive and everything works fine. Then I changed the 50-synaptics.config file. After trying to reboot Ubuntu Shows me the Logo and then freezes with a underscore on the left top.

Any solutions? Really want to use Linux.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you log into tty with CTRL+ALT+F1 ?

Comment: How? On bootup?

Comment: When its seems to be freezed.

Comment: No. Doesnt work

Comment: And just before? You can also try the [recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode)

Comment: No. Trying to boot in failsafe Mode has the same effect.

Comment: You can boot again from your USB drive (then select "Try Ubuntu") and undo your changes in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Firstly

I'm going to hope you made a back-up of your file before modifying it.

```
sudo cp /path/to/file !$.backup
```

Otherwise, I suggest in future you do this.

Do you remember what the original values were?  If not, I will explain how you can restore it.

### Secondly

You're going to need a new Live CD as you said you installed through a flash drive that will suffice.

- Place your USB into your machine and reboot it.
- Click the 'try Ubuntu' option when prompted.
- Once booted login as the ubuntu user and open a terminal.
- Within the terminal run `sudo su` - you're now the root user.

From this point you can mount your hard disc to your USB drive and as root you can change the files on your hard disk through the mount.

To view your discs execute: `fdisk -l`

*NOTE: if you are not root you will not see all partitions*

You should see a partition table similar to:

```
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048    62513151    31255552   83  Linux
/dev/sda2        62513152    90644479    14065664   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3        90644480   625141759   267248640   83  Linux
```

*/dev/*  is the directory in linux for devices, and linux usually has three - grub; swap space and storage volume.  You want the device that has *Device Boot* with an asterisk (*)

```
$ cd /mnt
$ mkdir hdd
$ mount /dev/sda1 hdd
```

Now your hard disk should be mounted to your USB; you can access it by: `cd /mnt/hdd`.  If you backed up your file you should be able to simply copy it back.  If not you could copy the file from your USB:

```
cp /path/to/file /mnt/hdd/path/to/file
```

Notice your hard disk root is actually `/mnt/hdd` and that `/` is your USB drive.

Once complete you can unmount your drive:

```
$ cd /mnt/
$ umount hdd
$ reboot
```

*Hopefully this helps, although not in all cases it will*

Comment: Thank you very much guys. 

My fault was that in 50-synaptics.config i forgot to comment a line. 

Now everything works perfect. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Boot the system via usb-stick again, choose **"Try Ubuntu"**, open a terminal by typing  **ALT+F2** and entering **gnome-terminal**.

In the terminal run the following command:

```
sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0009ac04

  Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1       13206     6655792+   7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda2           13207      232581   110565000    5  Extended
/dev/sda5          228706      232484     1904616   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6           13207      228705   108611464+  83  Linux
/dev/sda7          232485      232581       48856+  83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdb: 4051 MB, 4051697664 bytes
83 heads, 12 sectors/track, 7945 cylinders, total 7913472 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00099e83

  Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *          62     7910095     3955017    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

In this case /dev/sda6 (ATTENTION, this varies from install to install!) is the Linux-Root-Partition, which you can check by running

```
sudo mount /dev/sda6 /mnt
ls /mnt
```

and you'll get the / directory tree:

```
bin     dev      home      media     proc      sbin     tmp     var
boot    etc      lib       opt       root      sys      usr
```

afther that run:

```
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo chroot /mnt
```

with this commands you're now on your harddisk. Undo any changes you did after the install using your harddisk-user and password (e.g. playing with your synaptic-config), run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and try to reboot.

These are the instructions corresponding to your problem [from the ubuntu community help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery)!